# Searching for issues closed after their respective due dates

Tags: redmine

I can find overdue issues that are not closed using filter: `date due` less than today.

But is there a possibility to list only issues that were closed after their respective due dates?
I cannot set `date-due` to less than `close-date`.

Comment: Possibly an outstanding defect? https://www.redmine.org/issues/11426

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace: Sorry. English is not my native language. I don't know why I've treated overdue word as noun when it's an adjective.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs: I don't think so. There is nothing about closed overdue issues in this defect.

Comment: If an issue is closed, it cannot be overdue. Do you want to search for issues that were closed after their respective due date?

Comment: @AshokRamachandran: Yes.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new custom field

Name: "Overdue" 
Type: "Number" 
Formula: IIf(DateDiff("d",[Finish],Date(),1,1)>0,DateDiff("d",[Finish],Date(),1,1),0)
Rollup: Maximum (for group summary rows)

Now create a new filter and use it 
[Overdue] > 0

You also this custom field as a new column, and set is as graphic indicator like Red Yellow Green based on your requirements.

Comment: Is this "Formula" standard thing in Redmine? Because I've found only plugins that work with EasyRedmine only. Also there are requests for "custom fileds with mathematical calculation" in redmine project, but either of them has been successfully resolved and implemented.